# Mapping a remote serial port to a Debian VM

Tags: debian, ethernet, serial, mapping

I have a Debian Stretch VM that is dynamically migrated between a few hosts. I need to connect a serial (RS-232) modem to it. Unfortunately, I cannot use the hypervisor for this.

I am looking for a reliable method of mapping a serial port from one (physical) server to a VM (in a serial-over-ethernet manner), but there's a requirement that this must provide a virtual device file (like /dev/ttySX) on the VM. Additionally, it'd be highly desired if the whole setup could re-establish the connection after rebooting either of the servers, without requiring manual intervention.

Comment: u need to passthrough it but you dont told us which hypervisor you used...

Comment: As I wrote, I cannot use the hypervisor for direct passthrough from host to VM (I am not managing the virtualization environment, it's 3rd party). Only thing I can use is some sort of serial mapping over IP.

Comment: then use google for serial to tcp/ip i think these meet your requirments